# Why when drawing only the black pixels to a new image it's almost not showing any black pixels?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Read_Drawn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"d:\drawplane1.jpg");
            Bitmap mynewimage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

            for (int i = 0; i < image.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
                {
                    Color c = image.GetPixel(j, i);

                    if (c.R == 0 && c.G == 0 && c.B == 0)
                    {
                        mynewimage.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Black);
                    }
                }
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = mynewimage;
        }
    }
}
```

If I just assign the image to the pictureBox1 it will show png fine in the pictureBox1 but I want now to show only the black pixels I mean to show only the draw without the white background but it's showing only few if at all black pixels in the pictureBox1.

If I'm doing :

```
if (c.R == 0 && c.G == 0 && c.B == 0)
                    {
                        mynewimage.SetPixel(j, i,c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mynewimage.SetPixel(j, i, c);
                    }
```

Then it will draw a copy of the original file image but I want only the black draw without the white background.

Update :

This is the original image :

[image: Airplane]

I want to get only the drawn airplane without the white background and without any other stuff.

This is the script now :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Read_Drawn_Sketches
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap bmp;
        private Bitmap image;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
            trackBar1.Maximum = 50;

            image = new Bitmap(@"d:\drawplane1.jpg");
           
            bmp = (CreateNonIndexedImage(image));
            ConvertImageToBlackAndWhite(bmp);
            GetImagePixels();
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }

        private void GetImagePixels()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < image.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
                {
                    Color c = image.GetPixel(j, i);

                    if (c.R == 255 && c.G == 255 && c.B == 255) // white is an equal mix of every colour
                    {
                        bmp.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Transparent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void ConvertImageToBlackAndWhite(Bitmap SourceImage)
        {
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(SourceImage)) // SourceImage is a Bitmap object
            {
                var gray_matrix = new float[][] {
                new float[] { 0.299f, 0.299f, 0.299f, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0.587f, 0.587f, 0.587f, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0.114f, 0.114f, 0.114f, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0,      0,      0,      1, 0 },
                new float[] { 0,      0,      0,      0, 1 }
            };

                var ia = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes();
                ia.SetColorMatrix(new System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(gray_matrix));
                ia.SetThreshold(trackBar1.Value); // Change this threshold as needed
                var rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, SourceImage.Width, SourceImage.Height);
                gr.DrawImage(SourceImage, rc, 0, 0, SourceImage.Width, SourceImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
            }
        }

        public Bitmap CreateNonIndexedImage(Image src)
        {
            Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
            {
                gfx.DrawImage(src, 0, 0);
            }

            return newBmp;
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bmp = (CreateNonIndexedImage(image));
            ConvertImageToBlackAndWhite(bmp);

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
    }
}
```

When running the application I see in the pictureBox :
It looks like transparent but the airplane and other things that was in black are in white. I want it to be transparent but to keep only the black drawn.

[image: Result]

Now if I'm moving the trackBar by one to the right I'm getting this :
It's ion black but the background is now not transparent :

[image: trackBar moved one to the right]

Now I moved the trackbar a bit more to the right now you can see more black stuff around the airplane :

[image: More to the right a bit the trackbar]

And last I moved the trackbar to the far end to the right and this is I think how it should be the airplane but the background should be transparent and not white:

[image: The airplane but the background should be transparent not white]

The main goal is to take the image source from the hard disk and get only the airplane in black with transparent background and I prefer to make it in the code without an external tool or in some website even if it's more slower.

This is a link for the image file : https://easyupload.io/3l01vf

Comment: For all those pixels you don't draw, do you want them to be white or transparent?

Comment: `mynewimage.SetPixel(j, i,c);`  What's going on here?  You have this line for the `if` and the `else`.

Comment: Your source Bitmaps probably has very few (completely) black pixels. Maybe, as already suggested, use a ColorMatrix to convert the source image to black & white (with a threshold) or add a tolerance (so you don't look for pixels that are exactly `(0, 0, 0)`, but somewhat near it. Adjust the tolerance as needed, maybe using a TrackBar). As already suggested (2), use `Bitmap.LockBits()` to parse the imagedata.

Comment: @CaiusJard Transparent.

Comment: @LarsTech that's a test code

Comment: I've decided to delete my answer to your question because I have a moral objection to what I believe you're trying to do, namely to remove 123RF's watermarking from this image so you can use it in violation of their terms and conditions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if you want to remove whiteback ground and make it transparent, you want to look for color = 255. So that would be:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"d:\drawplane1.jpg");
            Bitmap mynewimage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

            for (int i = 0; i < image.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
                {
                    Color c = image.GetPixel(j, i);

                    if (c.R == 255 && c.G == 255 && c.B == 255) // white is an equal mix of every colour
                    {
                        mynewimage.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Transparent);
                    }
                }
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = mynewimage;
```

Note: this only works for complete white. If your background has some slightly different shades of white, you may need to use a range instead, such as `200 < c.R && c.R < 255 &&..` but I don't know how your image looks like so you'll have to play with the numbers yourself.

All that said, if your goal is to just remove the image background, you can use a free online background image remover. I normally just do that, works very quickly.

Comment: I will update my question with what I did and the original image.